# Convert a nonplanar graph into a planar one

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Is there a way to convert a nonplanar graph into a planar one, but instead of deleting edges, the only allowed action is to add nodes

Answer (score 3):

Logically , that is not Possible.

**(Proof 1)** Suppose there was a way to add nodes to convert $NP$ a Non-Planar graph into $P$ a Planar graph.
Draw $P$ on a Plane without crossings. Now "delete" the added nodes to get back $NP$ which will still be drawn on a Plane without crossings ! Hence $NP$ is itself a Planar graph !
Contradiction !

**(Proof 2)** Non-Planar graph has a subgraph which makes it Non-Planar. When we add nodes , that subgraph still Exists (the new graph still has the same subgraph) hence it will still be Non-Planar : We can never get a Planar graph with the addition of nodes.
The subgraphs which may make a given graph Non-Planar :
$K_5$ & $K_{3,3}$
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski's_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem)
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner's_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem)